# Keep the text formatting without html tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div:

```
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <br><br>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <br><br>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>
```

If I use:

```
MyInfo = $(".container").html();
```

I get all the `html` with `/n, /t, <br><br>` and so on.

If I instead use:

```
MyInfo = $(".container").text();
```

All formatting is dropped.
Is there any way to keep the formatting (but `drop html tags`, without using `replace`), so the output would look something like that:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Text isn't magically formatted. You need the HTML in order to retain that format

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes, but is there any way to keep the formatting without html tags?

Comment: replace all <*> with '' I guess....

Comment: I believe he answered that...

Comment: @AtheistP3ace So it is the `only` solution?

Comment: how else would you describe the 'format' of the text?? how would you represent new lines without the new line there??

Comment: HTML and CSS are what format things on the web. If you are attempting to keep anything other than line breaks, yes it is the only solution. You could probably write some code to keep where lines break but at the end of day you will still have some special characters in the text to achieve that.

Comment: @user1665355 you mention in comments below that this is within `Node.js` and you are actually using `Cheerio`. is this true? if so, maybe update the tags and question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `innerText`.  jQuery `text()` strips out line breaks and all formatting.

HTML (note addition of an `id` to your `div`):

```
<div id="containertext" class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <br><br>
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <br><br>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById("containertext").innerText);
```

Yields:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
>   do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
>   laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
>   esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsz34509/

Keep in mind it won't exactly keep the whitespace (like between `, sed do` on the first line) breaks, but does enforce the `<br>` line breaks.

Cool reference on `innerText` usage : http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Comment: Ok thanks, but I use it in `node.js`, so I am not sure that ``document.getElementById` works in node.js?

Comment: @user1665355 it's raw javascript, so it will just work.

Comment: No, it crashes: `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. I use `cheerio`

Comment: You have this on the browser side right? ``document`` is supported going back to the Netscape days.

Comment: DOM and Javascript are different, document and Node.innerText (afaik) are part of DOM. OP mentions nodejs, which doesn't have a DOM. libraries like Cheerio abstract these things like jQuery does, and likely does the same thing as jQuery.text() (although I haven't checked the source).

Comment: @rlemon Ok, but do you know of some way in `cheerio` to accomplish something like `document.getElementById("containertext").innerText`

Comment: cheerio lets you use selectors, so getting the element is fine enough. And no, I don't know of a way to do what you're talking about. But you might want to update your question to reflect your actual problem.